# scala ConfigException on ConfigFactory.parseFile

Tags: scala

I am new to Scala, guide me how to return custom exception message if `t2=` (blank)

I have conf like below:

test.conf

```
t1=30
t2=
```

In my case this t2 need to be blank can not specify like t2="" because this conf file comes from other person

I am getting ConfigException on parseFile if `t2=` (blank)

```
import java.io.File
import com.typesafe.config.Config 
import com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory

trait ConfigProvider {
    val config: Config
}

trait FileConfigProvider extends ConfigProvider {
    lazy override val config: Config = ConfigFactory.parseFile(new File(configfilePath))
    val configfilePath: String
}


object TestConfig extends FileConfigProvider with Serializable {

    override lazy val configfilePath: String = getTestConfig.filePath 
    private val defaultArgs = ProgramArgs() 
    var conf: Option[ProgramArgs] = None

   def getTestConfig: ProgramArgs conf.getOrElse(defaultArgs)
}
```

in some other file i am reading

```
println(config.getString("t1")) 
println(config.getString("t2"))
```

I am getting `ConfigException` on `ConfigFactory.parseFile` line

how to handle exception here or how to print custom exception message if `t2=` (blank)

Comment: Why down vote the question? It may be not useful for you but may be for others, If something is really wrong with question then correct the person who is asking question, at least tell him what is wrong with the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can just catch exception.

```
try {
  parseConfig()
} catch {
  case e: ConfigException =>
    println("Your config is broken:")
    println(e.getMessage)
    defaultConfig // or exit or throw new MyOwnException(e) or whatever
}
```

It should be enough information to let whoever provided config, to fix it.

Comment: as you mentioned i tried this  `trait FileConfigProvider extends ConfigProvider {
try {
 lazy override val config: Config = ConfigFactory.parseFile(new File(configfilePath))
 val configfilePath: String
} catch {
  case e: ConfigException =>
    println("Your config is broken:")
    println(e.getMessage)
    defaultConfig // or exit or throw new MyOwnException(e) or whatever
}
} ` but getting error in intellij 
Error: Wrong Forward Refenrence on new File(configfilePath)
Error: lazy value may not be abstract
Error: override modifier is not allowed here

Comment: You used try in class body (constructor) instead of within method.

Comment: @Mateusez guide me here please , where should i place try catch in my code ?

Answer (score 0):

Check out [pure-config](https://github.com/pureconfig/pureconfig#quick-start) it has a nice support for parsing config files into case classes and reports errors in a nice way too